# How to run OSGeo4W shell for molodensky transform?

Tags: proj, datum

I'm a beginner with Proj, so I just downloaded proj, and I'm using the OSGeo4W Shell and when I try to run the [example](https://proj.org/operations/transformations/molodensky.html?highlight=transformation)

`proj=molodensky a=6378160 rf=298.25 da=-23 df=-8.120449e-8  dx=-134 dy=-48 dz=149 abridged` that is listed on the Proj website I get the error:

`projection initialization failure
cause: invalid projection system error (-9999)
program abnormally terminated`

I've tried looking up this error message but I can't find anything about it. Do I need to download something else to get the command to work? I'm on a Windows 10 computer.

Comment: Did you use cs2cs https://proj.org/apps/cs2cs.html or what?